# stat_smooth not displayed on the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the data set shown below, I ran this command to draw a line graph with an overlaid smooth curve:

```
ggplot(tmp,
       aes(CalendarMonth, Score)) +
  geom_line(stat='identity', group = 1) + ylim(0, 3) +
  theme_few() + ylab('Average score in the month') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(CalendarMonth, Score), method='loess')
```

But this draws only a line graph, i.e. whether I run the `stat_smooth` part or leave it out, the output does not change, and the smooth curve is not overlaid. What am I missing here?

Data:

```
tmp <- data.frame(
  CalendarMonth = c('2012-07', '2012-08', '2012-06', '2012-05', '2012-04', '2012-09',
  '2012-10', '2012-11', '2012-12', '2013-01', '2013-02', '2013-03', '2013-04', '2013-05',
  '2013-06', '2013-07', '2013-08', '2013-09', '2013-10', '2013-11', '2013-12', '2014-01',
  '2014-02', '2014-03', '2014-04', '2014-05', '2014-06', '2014-07', '2014-08', '2014-09',
  '2014-10', '2014-11', '2014-12', '2015-01', '2015-02', '2015-03', '2015-04', '2015-05',
  '2015-06', '2015-07', '2015-08', '2015-09', '2015-10', '2015-11', '2015-12', '2016-01',
  '2016-02', '2016-03', '2016-04', '2016-05', '2016-06', '2016-07', '2016-08', '2016-09',
  '2016-10', '2016-11', '2016-12', '2017-01', '2017-02', '2017-03', '2017-04', '2017-05',
  '2017-06', '2017-07', '2017-08', '2017-09'),
  Score = c(2.716667, 2.577465, 2.615385, 3.000000, 3.000000, 2.446429,
  2.426667, 2.683544, 2.526316, 2.568966, 2.506849, 2.537500, 2.578125,
  2.470588, 2.741935, 2.560261, 2.479195, 2.545605, 2.577778, 2.539216,
  2.556492, 2.535593, 2.567829, 2.557214, 2.587662, 2.580189, 2.512069,
  2.572402, 2.582792, 2.555938, 2.512586, 2.561224, 2.572308, 2.557940,
  2.540000, 2.593333, 2.513274, 2.566952, 2.548649, 2.623223, 2.565079,
  2.537344, 2.516667, 2.509485, 2.519084, 2.544262, 2.612795, 2.496429,
  2.467128, 2.596226, 2.560714, 2.563253, 2.588462, 2.569395, 2.668919,
  2.581197, 2.543253, 2.524648, 2.594796, 2.551613, 2.583333, 2.474074,
  2.627306, 2.505017, 2.561086, 2.554545)
)
```

Comment: Convert `CalendarMonth` to integer in the `stat_smooth()` call; i.e. `aes(as.integer(CalendarMonth),Score)`.

Comment: That did not fully work. But `aes(as.integer(as.factor(CalendarMonth))` did work. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as such

Comment: Actually, my solution works given the information you provided in the question. If you needed to convert that column to a factor first, that means that the data on your machine is not the same as what you provided in the question. Calling `data.frame()` on the character vector will, by default, create a factor, so `as.integer` will work without any additional commands.

Comment: Fair. I had simplified the question and through that, become oblivious to the fact that my original code had `stringsAsFactors = F` in it.

Comment: I still think the credit of the answer should go to you, so if you post this as an answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data type is important, and as @joran mentioned in the comment, your data will need to change type before you can have a proper display.

We can quickly troubleshoot your issue with `str`:

```
> str(tmp)
'data.frame':   66 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ CalendarMonth: Factor w/ 66 levels "2012-04","2012-05",..: 4 5 3 2 1 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Score        : num  2.72 2.58 2.62 3 3 ...
```

In general, when you create a data frame you will want to set the parameter `stringsAsFactors` to false. If you do, you'll need to first run `as.factor` before `as.integer`. Have a look at what `as.integer` does to your factored data.

```
> as.integer(as.character(tmp$CalendarMonth))
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[26] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[51] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> as.integer(as.factor(as.character(tmp$CalendarMonth)))
 [1]  4  5  3  2  1  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
[26] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
[51] 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66
```

You'll notice that because the data format is in a YYYY-MM pseudo-date format when converting from a factor to an integer the values become an ordered list of date ranges. In general, be careful when you notice these types of conversions in R. The `as.integer` is following an interesting format, where the character values are compared to determine the order. What might work in one format may not work on another. For example:

```
> df <- data.frame(month = c('jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'dec', 'apr'))
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ month: Factor w/ 5 levels "apr","dec","feb",..: 4 3 5 2 1
> as.integer(df$month)
[1] 4 3 5 2 1
```

Be sure you understand how the solution works, so as to avoid a potential headache in the future. With that being said:

```
> tmp$cm <- as.integer(tmp$CalendarMonth)
> ggplot(tmp,
+        aes(CalendarMonth, Score)) +
+     geom_line(stat='identity', group = 1) + ylim(0, 3) +
+     theme_few() + ylab('Average score in the month') +
+     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) +
+     stat_smooth(aes(cm, Score), method='loess')
```

Gets you the right graph:

[image]